# Need help reading files

Tags: java, read-write

I'm writing a mock stock market in Java, and I want the ability for the user to view stocks purchased. I decided the easiest way to do this is to write to a file. My problem is that every time I run this program and attempt to read from the file, it outputs the path it took to read it. The information I want is correctly written to the file, but it isn't reading from it the way I want.

Here is the code I used for the file reading section:

```
if (amountOfStocks1 >= 1) {
  Scanner stocksBought1 = new Scanner("stocksbought/stocksBought1.txt");

  while (stocksBought1.hasNext()) {
    String fileRead = stocksBought1.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fileRead);
  }
  stocksBought1.close();
  runMenu = 1;
}
```

There are 7 of these `amountOfStocks` if/else statements.

I'm not sure if that's enough information. If it's not, tell me what to put on, and I'll do that.

If you can help me fix this problem or if you know an easier way to read and write to files that would be great!

Comment: What is the *exact* behaviour you want to achieve? What is the behaviour that you get instead?

Comment: This is my first post sorry ahaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Scanner stocksBought1 = new Scanner("stocksbought/stocksBought1.txt");
```

Try:

```
Scanner stocksBought1 = new Scanner(new File("stocksbought/stocksBought1.txt"));
```

When you only pass a `String` to the `Scanner` constructor the `Scanner` just scans that `String`. If you give it a `File` it will scan the contents of the `File`.

Comment: I don't have a rep of 15 so I can't upvote it, but I selected it as the correct answer, still getting a grasp of this website.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using the FileReader object.  You would use code similar to the following:

```
import java.io.*; 
class FileReaderDemo { 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  { 
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("FileReaderDemo.java"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
    String s; 
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println(s); 
    } 
    fr.close(); 
  } 
}
```

In addition, you can use the FileWriter object to write to a file.  There's lots of examples on the internet.  Easy to find on simple Google search. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileReader.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
 }
```